# Multiple instances of the same Async task (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, windows-phone-7.1, task

After googeling for ages, and reading some stuff about async task in books. I made a my first program with an async task in it. Only to find out, that i can only start one task. I want to run the task more then once. This is where i found out that that doesn't seem to work. to be a little bit clearer, here are some parts of my code:

```
InitFunction(var);
```

This is the Task itself

```
    public async Task InitFunction(string var)
    {

            _VarHandle = await _AdsClient.GetSymhandleByNameAsync(var);

            _Data = await _AdsClient.ReadAsync<T>(_VarHandle);

            _AdsClient.AddNotificationAsync<T>(_VarHandle, AdsTransmissionMode.OnChange, 1000, this);

    }
```

This works like a charm when i execute the task only once.. But is there a possibility to run it multiple times. Something like this?

```
InitFunction(var1); 
InitFunction(var2); 
InitFunction(var3);
```

Because if i do this now (multiple tasks at once), the task it wants to start is still running, and it throws an exeption.

if someone could help me with this, that would be awesome!

~ Bart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async`/`await` can work perfectly with multiple tasks, and multiple tasks at once. However, sometimes different objects can place restrictions on how many asynchronous operations can be outstanding at one time.

For example, the `Ping` class can only be used to send one ping at a time. If you want to send multiple pings at once, you need to use multiple `Ping` instances.

I suspect the same problem is at play here: `_AdsClient` probably is restricted to a single asynchronous operation at a time. So, if you want multiple `InitFunction`s to be run at once, you'll have to use multiple instances of whatever type that is.

On the other hand, if you wanted to run `InitFunction` multiple times, one at a time, then you just need to add some `await`s to your calling code:

```
await InitFunction(var1);
await InitFunction(var2);
await InitFunction(var3);
```

This will probably work - unless `_AdsClient` has "one-time use" semantics. Some classes do have this restriction.

Comment: Oke, Thank you for your reply. But i just found out that it was indeed  a problem with a "one time" restriction. 

In AdsClient i tried to open a socket. This is where the second instance failed, because the socket was currently being, or was allready openend by the frist task. Thanks for your anwser, things are clear now!